# Issues with Newly Installed Devise Login (ActionController::UnknownFormat in RegistrationsController#create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just switched my app from a hand-made login system to use the `Devise` gem.  I have used this gem with many apps before, but have never had this issue.  All the views are implemented correctly and display when they should, but when I try to create a new registration I get the following error:

`ActionController::UnknownFormat in RegistrationsController#create`

The trace it gives is as follows:

```
responders (2.2.0) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:207:in `respond_with'
devise (4.2.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:32:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
/Users/elizabethbayardelle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/elizabethbayardelle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/elizabethbayardelle/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

When I attempt to log in, I also get a blank white screen that just says "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."

I think these errors are related, but as I have had no experience with this set of errors with `Devise` I'm not 100% sure.  Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong here?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

Here's the code for `registrations#new`:

```
<div class="hero-image-row">
  <div class="hero-image-outer text-center">
    <div class="hero-image-inner text-center">
      <%= image_tag 'Background 17.jpg', class: "hero-image",alt: "Beautiful golf hole by the ocean" %>
    </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
  </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
</div> <!-- row -->

<div class="overlap-hero-image">
  <div class="buffer-25"></div>
  <div class="buffer-50"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container text-center col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1" style="background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.8) !important">
      <h1 style="color: black">Sign Up</h1>

      <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>

        <div class="form-inputs text-left row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div> <!-- columns box -->
  </div> <!-- container -->
</div> <!-- overlap-tall-hero-image -->
```

Here's a supplemental `registrations_controller` for some added columns:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :gender, :birthday, :dom_hand, :sport, :g_years, :g_rounds, :g_practice, :handicap, :g_score, :admin)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :gender, :birthday, :dom_hand, :sport, :g_years, :g_rounds, :g_practice, :handicap, :g_score, :admin)
  end
end
```

And here's how it's reflected in my routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

Comment: Could you show us the registrations#new view code? Did you customized the Devise controllers or not?

Comment: @Leito I added the `registrations#new` code to the original post.  I did add a few columns to my `users` table, so I also included the `registrations_controller` and how I linked it using my routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Devise autogenerated this for both `registrations#new` and `sessions#new`:

```
  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

The error disappeared when I removed `(resource_name)` on each form.